# How can I insert into a Map<K, ?>?

Tags: java, generics, collections, awt, unbounded-wildcard

Normally, I would call this a bug, but this is in the Java Standard Library.

There is a method -- [`java.awt.Font.getAttributes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#getAttributes()) that returns a `Map<TextAttribute, ?>`.

Now, this threw me for a loop because I don't know how I can *insert* elements into this map. After all, the parameterized type for the values we are inserting is ?, so how can we insert?

If it was fetching, I would simply store whatever I get into `Object`, since that is a catch all, much like the unbounded wildcard "?" is.

But this is inserting. How can I insert unless I do an unsafe cast?

Comment: Yeah, I guess this question is a duplicate. Still, I will accept my own answer as it provides a clear reference of how to get from problem ---> solution for my case specifically.

Comment: Not to mention, this is one of the very few Java API's that people will run into this problem with, so my answer is doubly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself -- you cannot.

This is actually a clue that I was misusing the API. In my defense, the API was not very obvious. But long story short, there is a constructor that ***TAKES IN*** a `Map<TextAttribute, ?>`. This means that we are ***PROVIDING*** our own `Map` for them to use. Now, `Map<TextAttribute, Object>` can definitely fit into `Map<TextAttribute, ?>`, so that means that we are good for providing a value to pass into this constructor.

And if the goal is to see what the contents of the `Map` are so that we can construct/populate our own, simply extract each object out into an `Object` or `var`, then do some `instanceof` checks to see what it is. From there, you can construct the proper type `V` to put for your `Map<K, V>`.

Here is a simple code example to more clearly explain the point.

I want to insert a `TextAttribute` into a `java.awt.Font`.

```java
final Map<TextAttribute, Object> map = new HashMap<>(); //Empty map to hold ALL attributes

map.putAll(someFont.getAttributes()); //These are the pre-existing attributes on my font

map.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON); //Adding an attribute

final Font font = Font.getFont(map); //Create font that has the new attribute + old ones too
```

***EDIT*** - Special thanks as always to @Holger for showing an even better way to make this work. Here it is below.

```java
final Font font = 
    someFont
        .deriveFont
        (
            Map.of
            (
                TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH,
                TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON
            )
        )
        ;
```

If we look at the documentation for this method, [`Font.deriveFont(Map< extends AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute,?>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(java.util.Map)), we can see that it takes in a Map whose values are of type ?. Furthermore, the documentation itself says that it ***"Creates a new Font object by replicating the current Font object and applying a new set of font attributes to it."*** So, it makes a duplicate, and then applies the changes that you passed in as a parameter to it. This is a more efficient way of doing what I described earlier.

Comment: Your example can be simplified to `final Font font = someFont.deriveFont( Map.of(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON));` But you got the principles of this API right. It’s worth noting that an API like the `getAttributes()` method [is actually discouraged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html#:~:text=Using%20a%20wildcard%20as%20a%20return%20type,%20using%20the%20code%20to%20deal%20with%20wildcards.): “*Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards.*”